# how to install drupal with myisam and different collation

Tags: 7, installation

How to install Drupal with MyIsam instead of InnoDb and with utf8_unicode_ci collation?

I know there are ways to change/convert both afterwards, but maybe its possible to specify it as installation parameter - it would be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can do during the installation or you can convert

### For the installation, before you launch the install.php, you need to edit the "/includes/databases/mysql/schema.inc file.

```
// Provide defaults if needed.
$table += array(
  'mysql_engine' => 'MyISAM',    //Changed from Innodb to MyISAM
  'mysql_character_set' => 'utf8',
   mysql_collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',  //Added the collation
);

$sql .= 'ENGINE = ' . $table['mysql_engine'] . ' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET ' . $table['mysql_character_set'] . ' COLLATE ' . $table['mysql_collation'];
```

---

in case  you want to convert already created tables. put the site on maintenance mode and use phpmyadmin to convert the engines and collations